# Filling RichTextBox works from click-Event only

Tags: vb.net

I have a RichTextBox in a Form which I try to fill from a Module; I tried already a few different ways to get it to work, but I can't figure out what the actual problem is?

In my module I have an instance::

```
 Dim Protokoll_UI As New Form1
```

With this I fill the RichTextBox directly.

```
 Protokoll_UI.RichTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename)
```

I already tried to call a method in class Form1 from the module, too, but it didn't have any impact on it:

```
 Module Module1
   Public Sub get_protokoll()
     Protokoll_UI.Protokoll() 
   End sub
 End Module      

 Class Form1
   Public Sub Protokoll()
      Protokoll_UI.Text = File.ReadAllText(Dateiname)
   End Sub
 End Class
```

The funny thing is that I have a `ToolStripMenuItem.Click` Event in the Class as well in which I update the RichTextBox, and it doesn't matter how I fill the RichTextBox, I can call a sub or fill it directly, it works perfectly:

```
 Private Sub UpdateToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AktualisierenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Protokoll()
End Sub
```

Even changing the `WordWrap` property of the RichTextBox did not help. At the moment I have absolutely no idea where I could look to solve this problem.

Btw. this is the result when I search for the RichTextBox in the whole project.

[image]

Comment: Add Protokoll_UI.Show() to see it.

Comment: That you for your fast respond @HansPassant but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @dr.null their must be some sort of missunderstanding. I did this obviously

Comment: "In my module i have an instanz. --> Dim Protokoll_UI As New Form1"  Conclusion: Your instance of Form1 in the Module is NOT the same instance of Form1 that you're seeing on your screen.  Possible solutions: (1) PASS an instance of Form1 or the RichTextBox to your Module/Method, (2) Search the [OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0) collection ton find the existing instance.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you very much for your help. The problem is that I crated tow instance I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

In your module, just do:

`Form1.RichTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename)`

and remove the `Dim Protokoll_UI As New Form1` from it.

You can call the `Protokoll()` function in the module from Form1 because it's in a Module; modules are global, and usable by all forms/classes in the project.

Comment: This assumes either Form1 is the Startup Object, or it was displayed using only the default instance.  If Form1 was created and displayed with the "new" keyword, it won't work...